# docker unable to find host

Tags: node.js, docker

I am trying to create a successful transaction in OpenHIM using the instructions [here](http://openhim.org/docs/tutorial/mediators/basic-scaffold), however, when I am running

```
curl -v -X  GET http://localhost:5001/scaffold -H "Authorization: Basic $(echo -n test:test | base64)"
```

I am getting

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:5001...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5001 (#0)
> GET /scaffold HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5001
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 33
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Date: Sat, 02 Sep 2023 06:51:13 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=5
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

I started the container using

```
sudo docker run --network bridge --name scaffold --rm -p 3000:3000 scaffold
```

I also tried

```
sudo docker run --network host --name scaffold --rm -p 3000:3000 scaffold
```

But the error remains same.

The error logs say
[image: error_screenshot]
[image: node_error]

My  `sudo docker network ls` command gives output

```
NETWORK ID     NAME      DRIVER    SCOPE
f4adb7db49f6   bridge    bridge    local
99c1e811ad1c   host      host      local
0b718516b4f0   none      null      local
```

My Dockerfile has

```
FROM node:18-buster
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install
CMD npm start
EXPOSE 3000
```

And index.js has

```
'use strict'
import utils from 'openhim-mediator-utils'
import mediatorConfig from './mediatorConfig.json' assert {type: 'json'};
import express from 'express'
const app = express()
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("GET Request Called")
})

const openhimConfig = {
  username: 'root@openhim.org',
  password: 'sky@1Fall',
  apiURL: 'https://revamp.intelehealth.org:8080',
  trustSelfSigned: true
}

utils.registerMediator(openhimConfig, mediatorConfig, err => {
  if (err) {
    throw new Error(`Failed to register mediator. Check your Config. ${err}`)
  }
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port 3000...')
})
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ombs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.11",
    "@babel/node": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.14",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "openhim-mediator-utils": "^0.4.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.17.6"
  }
}
```

mediatorConfig.json

```
{
  "urn": "urn:mediator:tutorial_scaffold",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "Scaffold Mediator",
  "description": "Tutorial Scaffold Mediator",
  "defaultChannelConfig": [
    {
      "name": "Bootstrap Scaffold Mediator",
      "urlPattern": "^/scaffold$",
      "routes": [
        {
          "name": "Bootstrap Scaffold Mediator Route",
          "host": "scaffold",
          "path": "/",
          "port": "3000",
          "primary": true,
          "type": "http"
        }
      ],
      "allow": ["admin"],
      "methods": ["GET", "POST"],
      "type": "http"
    }
  ],
  "endpoints": [
    {
      "name": "Bootstrap Scaffold Mediator Endpoint",
      "host": "scaffold",
      "path": "/",
      "port": "3000",
      "primary": true,
      "type": "http"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Here](http://openhim.org/docs/tutorial/mediators/basic-scaffold)  it has following commands

```
docker build -t scaffold .

docker network ls

docker run --network tutorial_openhim --name scaffold --rm -p 3000:3000 scaffold
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Thanks

Any help anyone ? Greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're exposing port 3000, but trying to ping port 5001.

Comment: even if I expose 5001 , and do a sudo docker run --network host --name scaffold --rm -p 3000:5001 scaffold
the error remains the same @bumbread

Comment: Your curl command tries to access port 5001, however you're exposing an internal 5001 port as 3000. That is your localhost:3000 address should be pingable but you're pinging port 5001.

Comment: @bumbread this as well gives the same error : sudo docker run --network host --name scaffold --rm -p 5001:3000 scaffold
and in my Dockerfile I have EXPOSE 5001

Comment: You need to provide `package.json` and `mediatorConfig.json` for reproduce your error.

Comment: Also how to ran `openhim-mediator` docker image? I can't see it from your code share.

Comment: edited my code for package.json, mediatorConfig.json and page containing instructions on building mediator @BenchVue.  In case you want to do a anydesk session or teamviewer to guide, I am available. Thanks

Comment: I followed OpenHIM using the instructions step by step, I got this error `/app/index.js:3 import express from 'express'; ^^^^^^^ SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`  when I ran 'docker run ~'. But `node index.js` is fine in local. How to address this error. In your code step also same error. I am using Windows 11.

Comment: You missed `docker network create tutorial_openhim` step.

Comment: have you edited package.json to have the entry   "type": "module"

Comment: @BenchVue were you able to solve the problem? just wanted to check my docker commands , which one of them is right , and do I need to change my dockerfile EXPOSE from 3000 to 5001

Comment: I know how to fix import issue by add type module into package.json but this error still open in my Windows 11 with docker.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255149/discussion-between-satya-and-bench-vue).

Comment: sorry, I am not staying long at this time. Can you update via the comment channel?

Comment: > 2023-09-02 17:36:01.104 - error: [worker1] [64f32529c416130692d281db] Internal server error occured: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN scaffold
> 2023-09-02 17:36:01.110 - info: [worker1] All routes completed for transaction: 64f32529c416130692d281db
> 2023-09-02 17:36:01.110 - error: [worker1] Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN scaffold
> at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:109:26)
> 2023-09-02 17:36:01.114 - info: [worker1] Final status for transaction 64f32529c416130692d281db : Failed   -- Still the same